# Use boundedness & continuity to show the sequence is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

All I need a confirmation if my procedure is correct.

$1. \rightarrow$ $$f_n(x)= n\log\bigg(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\bigg),$$ $x \in (0, \infty).$

$2. \rightarrow$ $$f_n(x)= n(x^\frac{1}{n}-1),$$ $x\in [1,a], a>1.$

From $1.$, I have
$$|f'_n(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow n> \frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{x\epsilon}-1),$$ $x \in (0, \infty).$

At $x=0$ the sequence has a point of discontinuity and as $x \rightarrow \infty$, $f_n$ approaches to $0$ but in $(0,\infty)$ the $f_n(x)$ is continuous and $0<n\log(1+\frac{1}{nx})<(1+\frac{1}{nx})^n<1$ for large $n$ and an $M_n$ test gives $$\max_{x\in (0, \infty)}|f'_n(x)-g(x)|=0,$$ where $g(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f'_n(x).$

By applying the continuity and boundedness can I say $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent?

From $2.$, clearly I have that $f_n(x)$ is bounded and decreasing in $(-\infty, 0]$ and $f_n(x)$ has discontinuties as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(a^\frac{1}{n}-1)=0,$$ $a>1.$

So $f_n(x)$ is continuous and $0\leq f_n(x)<n$ but a little algebra shows that none of $f_n(x)$ or $f'_n(x)$ approaches to 0, rather they have discontinuity for larger $n$. Is is enough to say that $f_n(x)$ is non-uniform?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is $\log\bigg(\dfrac{1+nx}{nx}\bigg) = (x^\frac{1}{n}-1)$?

Comment: I did not mean it.

Comment: Well in step $1$ you have $f_n(x)= n\log\bigg(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\bigg)$ and  in step $2$ you have $f_n(x)= n(x^\frac{1}{n}-1)$ on overlapping intervals

Comment: To be honest I cannot follow your logic. And the answer is that (1) does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$, and (2) converges uniformly on $[1,a]$. For (1), notice that $f_n(x) \to \frac{1}{x}$ pointwise but the supremum distance between $f_n(x)$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,\infty)$ is $\infty$. For (2), if you know that $f_n$ is monotone decreasing in $n$ then a one-liner proof is available from Dini’s theorem, though utilizing Taylor theorem with explicit control over the remainder term also works.

Comment: Thinking upon (2) again, it seems that the mean value theorem is enough.

Comment: @SangchulLee, I got your hints and proved both of them. Thank you.